# How do do configure a Hudson linux slave to generate core files?

Tags: linux, hudson, coredump

I've seeing occasional segmentation faults in glibc on several different Fedora Core 9 Hudson Slaves.  I've attempted to configure each slave to generate core files and place them in /corefiles, but have had no luck.

Here is what I've done on each linux slave:

1) Create a corefile storage location
`sudo install -m 1777 -d /corefiles`

2) Directed the corefiles to the storage location by adding the following to */etc/sysctl.conf*
`kernel.core_pattern = /corefiles/core.%e-PID:%p-%t-signal_%s-%h`

3) Enabled unlimited corefiles for all users by adding the following to */etc/profile*
`ulimit -c unlimited`

Is there some additional Linux magic required or do I need to do something to the Hudson slave or JVM?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out :-).

The issue is Hudson invokes the bash shell as a non-interactive shell, which will bypass the ulimit setting in */etc/profile*.  The solution is to add the BASH_ENV environmental variable tothe Hudson slaves and set the value to a file with *ulimit -c unlimited* set.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reboot or run "sysctl -p" (as root) after editing /etc/sysctl.conf ?

Also, if i remember correctly, ulimit values are per user and calling ulimit wont survive a boot. You should add this to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*  soft  core  unlimited
```

Or call ulimit in the script that starts hudson if you don't wont everyone to produce coredumps.

Comment: Yes, I did reboot after the edits.  I didn't know about the limits.conf.  I'll give that a try.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if the /etc/security/limits.conf applies, this only is for pam_limits.  In any case it didn't fix the issue.